# How do I hide the public API methods of my extending class?

Tags: ios, api, design-patterns

I have written an DataAdapter library that has dependency(tightly coupled) with a core-data library (coredata library helps to store,manage data in the DB) and hence I create API's in DataAdapter class extending the core data class to have quick access to all the API's of core data class.

However, as I have extended the core data class in my DataAdapter class, all the API's in core data class is visible to the developer through DataAdapter class(which I don't want to happen, basically wanting him to use adapter API methods only.)

Eg: Core data has an API as

> - (CoreDataResponse *) getAllManagedObjectsOfEntity:(CoreDataRequest *)request;

DataAdapter has an API as `

> -(DBResponse *)getAllStoredRecordsFromDB;

The exact issue is, Xcode autosuggestion for adapter methods shows up core data API'S as well as below - But I want my developer using the data adapter to access only the API methods of DataAdapter, How can I achieve it?
[image]

Update -1: This is my Adapter header class extended with coredata

```
#import "CoreDataManager.h"

@interface DataAdapter : CoreDataManager
-(DBResponse *)getAllStoredRecordsFromDB;
@end
```

Comment: Write the import statement for CoreData library in implementation file of your DataAdapter library. Create all properties pertaining to CoreData in implementation file, implying them to be private.

Comment: As I have extended the CoreData library in the DataAdapter class, those CoreData API methods are still accessible through my DataAdapter class instance.

Comment: And also, As i'm extending adapter from core data, this import statement will have to be included in the adapter.h class file.

Comment: You can move the property related to adapter from Core Data in your implementation file. See I show you in the answer, how to create properties in implemenation file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In //DataAdapter.m

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface DataAdapter()
@property (strong, nonatomic) CoreDataAdapter *adapter;
@end

@implementation DataAdapter

@end
```

Comment: Agreed. This wouldn't expose core data API to the 3rd party developers, but shouldn't I extend CoreData class to access their API's with much ease than taking your approach?

Comment: If you dont want other people to access CoreData related properties, you need to make them private. This way you will be making it private and developers wont be able to access those properties. And I dont understand how this is difficult than declaring properties in header file, or having the import statement in header file?

Comment: Is there a way you see I can still achieve this by extending coredata in adapter?

Comment: I am confused now. What do you mean by extending Core Data? Please post code of what you have written in header file.

Comment: Try using @class CoreDataManager  in your DataAdapter.h. In DataAdapter.m use #import "CoreDataManager.h". Then check whether classes that have imported DataAdapter.h can access CoreDataManager.h or not.